# Keeping your own community's dinim vs. yuhara

Tags: minhag, middos-character-traits, bein-adam-lachavero, stringency-chumrah, yuhara

My chosen community--like every community, I suppose--has its own body of distinctive minhagim, horaos, chumras, hiddurim, and normative halachas. All, including the hiddurim, are observed with a high degree of commitment by a substantial cohort who see this as a matter of loyalty and love. People do not tend to deviate from them because of travel, convenience, or the minhag hamakom.

But I am trying to learn more about the halachos of yuhara, according to which it [seems](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41255/1516) that it may be forbidden to go above and beyond the basic halacha in public if others are not doing the same.

From [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43857/parameters-of-yuhara-for-women) it seems that in at least one case, a non-Torah-scholar may do an "extra" practice in public as long as all the Torah scholars and some of the balabatim are doing it. And from the Rema cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43864/1516), he may do an "extra" something if he is involved in "prishus and chassidus" in general. Of course, he may (must?) do what is correct l'chatchila even if others are doing only b'dieved or less. Other deviations from the norm, however, would seem to be discouraged.

- Is it really yuhara to keep, say, your kashrus standards all the time? I read a source saying that not drinking cholov stam is not yuhara, perhaps because this "act" is completely passive. But when it's a matter of requiring CY keilim--or, very complicated, refusing the meat of your Satmar Shabbos hosts--you are going to stick out. And yet I can't imagine allowing or requiring yeridah in a matter like kashrus just because "other people are doing it."
- What is a general guideline for what types of practices are doche and not doche hilchos yuhara? (Personal hachlatos/nedarim/chazakos? Things that you have genuine spiritual pleasure from, or a strong spiritual need to do? Communal and family minhagim? Explicit directives of the religious leader(s) of your community? Rulings of the poskim of your community? Chumras which everyone in your community keeps?) I'd appreciate "canonical" sources if they exist.

Related: [When should one change one's Minhag with one's Makom (and when should one not)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28055/when-should-one-change-ones-minhag-with-ones-makom-and-when-should-one-not)

[Chaba''d doesn't follow minhag hamakom?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93155/chabad-doesnt-follow-minhag-hamakom?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters of Yuhara - When should someone be concerned that he's overdoing it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41250/parameters-of-yuhara-when-should-someone-be-concerned-that-hes-overdoing-it)

Comment: I flagged it as duplicate: Hilchot Yuhara imply that a person keeps his traditions (as you call it community's traditions), therefore there's no reason to confront them.

Comment: This is possibly a [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). If you are contrasting two bad options, e.g. should you abandon your kashrus standards or should you demonstrate yuhara, the answer can be that there is a third option which is avoid the situation and be like R. Pinchas Ben Yair who [never ate at anyone's house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phinehas_ben_Jair#His_piety).

Comment: @Alex Perhaps, if you're not R' Pinchas ben Yair, *that* would be yuhara.

Comment: @Loewian If you tell someone that you won't eat at their house because you have higher kashrus standards, perhaps it would be. But I imagine there are ways to avoid eating at someone's house without displaying that you are holier than them.

Comment: Yahirut, meaning 'pride' is the absolute opposite of Chassidut. The general idea in Torah is that a person who indulges this character trait is challenging G-d and pushing the Shechina away. It is to be avoided as much a possible. The place where this is discussed is in relation to Avot. Here is a link to a Sefer Magen Avot 4:4 discussing the subject. https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avot.4.4.1?vhe=Magen_Avot,_Leipzig_1855&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: And this is based upon Bava Batra 98a by Rav Yehuda in the name of Rav (see there). The only one who is fit for pride is HaKadosh, baruch Hu. Bava Batra link: https://www.sefaria.org/Steinsaltz_on_Bava_Batra.98a?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Hebrew&lang=bi

Comment: @YaacovDeane So how does one negotiate this? I can't imagine having actual pride about my avodas H' and would almost say "halevay." But the appearance of pride when you're doing differently than everyone else is hard to avoid. What does one do? That is, what would a chasid do?

Comment: @DanF your comment got, um, disappeared -- but yes, I eat by Satmar, eat their meat, and am extremely humbled by them

Comment: @Alex I've been on both sides of this and can confirm that it's fairly transparent why one refuses someone's food. Refusing *everyone's* food might be safer as far as hurting people (ch"v), although not necessarily safer against yuhara...

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but...

There is an interesting responsum of [R. Sherira Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherira_Gaon). The question posed to him was what one should do in a place where people don't wear tefillin. Specifically, is there a problem of *yuhara* if you wear tefillin when everyone else does not? The question was compounded with an additional factor, namely, that the person wearing tefillin might not be the most scrupulous of individuals in his other religious activity, thereby accentuating the *yuhara* by specifically doing the mitzvah that no one else is doing while not caring about the other mitzvot.

R. Sherira's answer was pretty emphatic. He begins by saying that the concept of *yuhara* is applicable to something that is extra piety and not strict law. He then states simply that tefillin is a biblical commandment and there is no way to get out of it. You can't not fulfill a biblical commandment because of such concerns. Even if the person in question is a horrible Jew in general, it doesn't change the fact that he still has an obligation to wear tefillin. The fact that he doesn't fulfill other mitzvot is a shame, but has no halachic impact on his obligation to fulfill this mitzvah. R. Sherira added that if the person in question is a respected individual there is all the more reason for him to publicly wear tefillin so that the rest of the people will follow his example and start fulfilling the mitzvah, and for him not to do so would be a desecration of God's name.

That said, R. Sherira noted that if the person in question really is a "bad Jew" then it could smack of *yuhara* that the one mitzvah he does is the one that no one else does. In such a case the person must still wear tefillin (as mentioned above, since it is a biblical obligation) but should do it in private so as not to demonstrate *yuhara*.

From this responsum we can derive two important things:

1. Certain halachic obligations (e.g. biblical commandments) completely override any concerns of *yuhara*.
2. Even when halacha obligates you to do something, it doesn't necessarily make it not *yuhara*. You have to do it, but you also have to do whatever you can to eliminate the *yuhara* aspect (usually accomplished by doing it in private).

The responsum can be found in *Teshuvot U'Peirushei R. Sherira Gaon* 1:2, and with minor differences in *Teshuvot HaGeonim Im Teshuvot U'Pesakim Mei'Chachmei Provencia* §76.

Here is the actual text of the responsum:

**תשובות ופרושי ר' שרירא גאון א:ב**

> וששאלתם אמרי' בגמר' פושעי ישראל בגופן אמר רב קרקפתא דלא מנח תפילי
>   והאידנא מאי טעמ' זלזלי ביה רוביה דעלמ' אי משום מעשה דאלישע בעל כנפים
>   כבר פירשו גאונים הראשונים ההוא בשעת השמד ויש מקצת התלמידים שמניחין
>   תפילין מי מחזי כיוהרא או לא או דילמ' קיומי מצוה עדיף היאך מנהג אדונינו
>   ומנהג הישיבה ואם לא נהגו בכך מאיזה טעם ילמדו אדונינו
>
> הכין חזינא דבארץ ישראל מימים הראשונים כיון דנפישי שמדא ולא יכלי לאחותי
>   תפילי אשתכחן מנהון ובבל טובא הוו זהירין וביותר רבנן יושבי מדרשות והוא
>   איכא בתי דמיעבדן בהון תפילין ומאן דניחא ליה אתי וזבין כדקאמר ליה אביי
>   לרבינא תפילין השתא בי רב חבו שכיחי ושאר העם בחוצות לא הוו קבעין
>   דצריכין למנגע בגוים ודלמא חייפין בהו נדות וזבות אבל בעת תפילה קבעינן
>
> וכיון דהוה אתו מארץ ישראל להכא לא מחתינן תפילי ואזלי' מהכא להתם
>   ואשכחין ראשותא ורבנן דלא מחתין תפילי אימעוטי קליקלי בכל דור ודור
>   דאידמי להון לשאר עמא דצריכות גוף נקי כאלישע בעל כנפים וטובא פרישו להון
>   ראשונים דלא צריכין השתא כיון... והוה מחלין על נפשיהון ואמעיטו אבל
>   לאשתכוחי לגמרי חס ושלום דאישתכחו וטובא איכא במדינאתא וברוסתקי רבנן
>   וקשישי דמחתין תפילין ןזהירי רבנן לאחויי להדדי קשר של תפילין כדחוו למשה
>   דחוו ליה מן שמיא דאמר רב חנא בר ביזנא אמ' ר' שמעו' חסידא וראית את
>   אחורי מלמד שהראהו הקדוש ברוך הוא למשה קשר של תפילין מאחוריו ותדיר דקא
>   מכרזיננא ומודעיננא כדר' חייא בר אבא אמ' ר' יוחנן כל הקורא קרית שמע בלא
>   תפילין כאילו הקריב עולה בלא מנחה זבח בלא נסכים
>
> ומאן דקבע להו חס ושלום דמחזי כיוהרא [וליכא למיחש ליוהרא אלא] מידעם דלא
>   מיחייב ביה ועביד ליה רבים מידת חסידות כיון שכולי עלמ' לא קא מימנעי מן
>   ההיא מילתא והוא קא מימנע מינה או דקא עביד מאי דלא קעבדין כולי עלמ'
>   מיחזי כיוהרא כדתנן חתן פטור מקרית שמע ותנן בהדא חתן אם רוצה לקרות את
>   שמע לילה הראשון קורא רבן שמעו' בן גמליאל או[מר] לא כל הרוצה ליטול את
>   השם יטול ואף על גב דבהא לא חיישי רבנן ליוהרא ורבן שמעו' בן גמליאל קא
>   חייש ליוהרא באידך קא חיישי רבנן ליוהרא דקאמ' רבן שמעו' בן גמליאל יעשו
>   כל אדם עצמן כתלמיד חכם כתלמידי חכמים אבל רבנן לא קאמרי הכי משום
>   דחיישין ליוהרא וכולהו בדבר שאין חייב בו אבל תפילין דכל אדם חייבין בהם
>   ומשום דאחריני פשעין מאן דלא פשע לא מחזי כיוהרא אבל ודאי אי אניש פריצא
>   הוא ולא ידע בשמור מצות והדא מילת' דרבים פושעים (בההוא) [בה הוא] דקא
>   מזדהר ביה אבל מילי אחרנייתא דרבים זהירין בהו קא פשע אית למיחש ליוהרא
>   ולמימנעיה לא איפשר דהא[י]כין מימנע אדם ממצוה משום דקא פשע מן חדא מימנע
>   מן חדא אלא אי הכי הוא מיבעי ליה לאחותיה בביתיה ושלא בפני רבים [דאמרין]
>   מאי טעמ' זהיר האי בהדא מצוה מכל מצות אלא לאחויי יוהרא אבל אי גברא דלא
>   פריץ דלא ידע דפשע במצות אף עלגב דלא ידיע בגוף נקי ובזהירות וחסידות לא
>   מיחזי כיוהרא ואיכא למימ' דאחרין נמי כד חזיין ליה עבדין כוותיה וביותר
>   מאן דאיתיה גברא רבה קשישא מעליא דאי לא קבע קאי בעון דחילול השם

**תשובות הגאונים עם תשובות ופסקים מחכמי פרובינצא סימן עו**

> וששאלתם אמרי בגמר' פושעי ישראל בגופן אמר רב קרקפתא דלא מנח תפילי
>   והאידנא מאי טעמא זלזלי ביה רוביה דעלמא אי משום מעשה דאלישע בעל כנפים
>   כבר פרישו גאונים הראשונים ההוא בשעת השמד ויש מקצת התלמידים שמניחין
>   תפילין מי מחזי כיוהרא או לא או דילמא קיומי מצוה עדיף היאך מנהג אדונינו
>   ומנהג הישיבה ואם לא נהגו בכך מאיזה טעם ילמדנו אדונינו הכין חזינא דבארץ
>   ישראל מימים הראשונים כיון דנפישי שמדא ולא יכלי לאחותי תפילי  אשתכחן
>   מנהון ובבבל טובא הוו זהירין וביותר רבנן יושבי מדרשות והוא איכא בתי
>   דמיעבדן בהון תפילין ומאן דניחא ליה אתי וזבין כדקאמר ליה אביי לרבינא
>   תפילין השתא בי רב חבו שכיחי ושאר העם בחוצות לא הוו קבעין דצריכין למנגע
>   בגוים ודלמא חייפין בהו נדות וזבות אבל בעת תפילה קבעינן וכיון דהוה אתו
>   מארץ ישראל להכא לא מחתינן תפילין ואזלי מהכא להתם ומשכחין דאשותא ורבנן
>   דלא מחתין תפילין אימעיטי קלי קלי בכל דור ודור דאידמי להון לשאר עמא
>   דצריכות גוף נקי כאלישע בעל כנפים וטובא פרישו להון ראשונים דלא צריכין
>   השתא כיון והוה מחלין על נפשיהון ואמעיטו אבל לאשתכוחי לגמרי חס ושלום
>   דאישתכחו וטובא איכא במדינאתא וברוסתקי רבנן וקשישי דמחתין תפילין וזהירי
>   רבנן לאחויי להדדי קשר של תפילין כדהוו למשה דהוו ליה מן שמיא דאמר רב
>   חנא בר ביזנא אמר ר' שמעון חסידא וראית את אחורי מלמד שהראהו הקב"ה למשה
>   קשר של תפילין מאחוריו ותדיר דקא מכרזיננא ומודעיננא כדר' חייא בר אבא
>   אמר ר' יוחנן דאמר ר' חייא בר אבא אמר ר' יוחנן כל הקורא קרית שמע בלא
>   תפילין כאילו הקריב עולה בלא מנחה זבח בלא נסכים ומאן דקבע להו חם ושלום
>   דמחזי כיוהרא מידעם דלא מיחייב ביה ועביד ליה רבים מידת חסידות כיון
>   שכולי עלמא לא קא מימנעי מן ההיא מילתא והוא קא מימנע מינה או דקא עביד
>   מאי דלא קא עבדינן כולי עלמא מיחזי כיוהרא כדתנן חתן פטור מקרית שמע ותנן
>   בהדא חתן אם רוצה לקרות את שמע לילה הראשון קורא רבן שמעון בן גמליאל
>   אומר לא כל הרוצה ליטול את השם יטול ואע"ג דבהא לא חיישי רבנן ליוהרא
>   ורבן שמעון בן גמליאל קא חייש ליוהרא באידך קא חיישי רבנן ליוהרא דקאמר
>   רבן שמעון בן גמליאל יעשו כל אדם עצמן כתלמידי חכמים אבל רבנן לא קאמרי
>   הני משום דחיישין ליוהרא וכולהו בדבר שאין חייב בו אבל תפילין דכל אדם
>   חייבין בהם ומשום דאחריני פשעין מאן דלא פשע לא מחזי כיוהרא אבל ודאי אי
>   אניש פריצא הוא ולא ידע בשמור מצות והדא מילתא דרבים פושעים בה הוא דקא
>   מזדהר ביה אבל מילי אחרנייתא דרבים זהירין בהו קא פשע אית למיחש ליוהרא
>   ולמימנעיה לא איפשר דה[י]כין מימנע אדם ממצוה משום דקא פשע מן חדא מימנע
>   מן חדא אלא אי הכי הוא מיבעי ליה לאחותיה בביתיה ושלא בפני רבים [דאמרין]
>   מאי טעמא זהיר האי בהדא מצוה מכל מצות אלא לאחויי יוהרא אבל אי גברא דלא
>   פריץ דלא ידע דפשע במצות אע"ג דלא ידיע בגוף נקי ובזהירות וחסידות לא
>   מיחזי כיוהרא ואיכא למימר דאחרין נמי כד חזיין ליה עבדין כוותיה וביותר
>   מאן דאיתיה גברא רבה קשישא מעליא דאי לא קבע קאי בעון דחילול השם

Comment: Great answer, but I am somewhat surprised that rabbinical halachos are not generally doche yuhara, according to this guy. The reason this surprises me is that it seems to leave a lot of room for personal interpretation that, if accomplished incorrectly, could lead to mitzvos not being kept

Comment: You might be reading too much into the difference between biblical and rabbinical laws. The responsum spoke about a biblical law because that's the question that was asked. Earlier in the responsum he seems to indicate that yuhara is only by midas chassidus. I will edit the answer to try to make it more clear.

Comment: @Alex This is a good answer and Sherira Gaon is great. With no disagreements, a couple comments. 1) regarding biblical commandments, consider Birkat Kohanim. By most, it is not done every day, in all places. 2) consider the meaning of the blessing from Bilaam to the Jewish people, “How goodly are your tents, Yaacov...etc.” 3) the episode with Rabbi Adin Even Yisroel Steinsaltz and the Jew who told him that he never keeps Shabbat, and in fact eats bacon every Shabbat.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Could you explain a bit more what you mean with #2 and #3? I also don't think I know this Steinsaltz story

Comment: @SAH point 2 is really fairly simple. The emphasis is that the praise of the Jewish people at that moment was that they mind their own business. That comes about from humility (anavut). The Magen Avot makes this contrast that yuhara is an indication of a lack of humility.

Comment: @SAH The Steinsaltz story is that at one point Rabbi Steinsaltz was confronted by a non-observant Jew (in the words borrowed from Rav Sherira Gaon above, 'the really bad Jew') while exiting some talk he had just given. The non-observant Jew took pride in never keeping Shabbat and told Rabbi Steinsaltz that he even made a point of cooking and eating bacon every Shabbat. Rabbi Steinsaltz stopped and asked him if it was every Shabbat and only on Shabbat. And the individual replied, "Yes, every Shabbat and only on Shabbat."

Comment: Rav Steinsaltz explained to him that his soul was trying to observe Shabbat by preparing and eating the bacon only on Shabbat. It was the wrong way to sanctify the day, and Steinsaltz said he would have chosen another way. But it was to this individuals merit. His soul was attempting to fulfill his obligation to keep Shabbat. No Yuhara on the part of Rabbi Steinsaltz and an effort to show the individual that he had merit in Rabbi Steinsaltz's eyes for truly wanting to keep Shabbat.